# Correct implementation of a copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I was playing around in C++ to get familiar with classes. I wrote a simple Class that represents vectors. I wanted to implement a copy constructor as follows:

```
Vector(Vector _v);
Vector::Vector(Vector _v) {
    set_vector(_v.x, _v.y);
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
vector.h:17:25: error: invalid constructor; you probably meant ‘Vector (const Vector&)’
         Vector(Vector _v);        // Copy constructor
                         ^
vector.h:52:1: error: no declaration matches ‘Vector::Vector(Vector)’
 Vector::Vector(Vector _v) {
 ^~~~~~
```

After chaning it to

```
Vector(const Vector& _v);
Vector::Vector(const Vector& _v) {
    set_vector(_v.x, _v.y);
}
```

it worked. Why is that?

Here is the header file `vector.h`:

```
class Vector {
    private:
        double x,y;

    public:
        Vector();                        // Standard constructor
        Vector(double _x, double _y);    // General constructor
        Vector(const Vector& _v);        // Copy constructor WORKING
        //Vector(Vector _v);        // Copy constructor ERROR

        ~Vector();
};

void Vector::set_vector(double _x, double _y) {
    x = _x;
    y = _y;
    return;
}

Vector::Vector() {
    set_vector(0,0);
}

Vector::Vector(double _x, double _y) {
    set_vector(_x, _y);
}

Vector::~Vector() {}

// WORKING
Vector::Vector(const Vector& _v) {
    set_vector(_v.x, _v.y);
}

// ERROR
//Vector::Vector(Vector _v) {
//    set_vector(_v.x, _v.y);
//}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version would lead to infinite recursion, so it is not allowed to define copy constructors in such way.

If it was allowed, the following would happen:

First, we try to call copy constructor:

```
Vector v1 {};
Vector v2 {v1};
```

This calls `Vector::Vector(Vector _v)`, but in order to initialize `_v`, we need to call copy constructor again (because it's passed by value a.k.a. by copy).

Since there's no single way to make it not result in infinite recursion, it is simply forbidden.

Comment: Why is the copy constructor called more than one time? Why does `const Vector &v` prevent an infinite recursion?

Comment: @Samuel: As stated in the answer: "*in order to initailize[sic] `_v`, we need to call copy constructor again*". Value parameters are *values*; C++ is not Java/C#. If you declare a (non-reference) variable, it is a distinct object with a different address and identity from any other (complete) object. So to call such a function, you must create a distinct object, which would thus be a copy of the argument you give. And to do that, you call the copy constructor... which takes a distinct object that must be created from the argument by calling the copy constructor... etc.

Comment: @Samuel Your original version took the argument "by value", which implies a *copy*. Thus the copy constructor would need to be called - while already in the context of the copy constructor - see the recursion?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing the value to be copied by value. So, in order to call the copy constructor, the compiler needs to copy the argument, but he doesn't know yet how to copy `Vector`s, because that's precisely what you are trying to define.

Otherwise, as others as stated, it would lead to infinite recursion: to copy an object, you have to copy the constructor's argument first, so let's call the copy constructor to copy the argument, which again, requires its argument is copied first.

You need to receive a reference to prevent a copy is made before doing the actual copy.

Both `Vector&` and `Vector const&` would work, however, with the `const&` version, you promise to the user you won't modify the object he is passing to you. Also, if you accidentally modify the argument, the compiler will complain, so you will be warned in case you do something unintended.

Remember, type safety is not about restrictions, is about expressing intention so the compiler can help you.